# How to kill Dozers effectively?

Tags: payday-2

I often find myself getting killed by Dozers, especially on higher difficulty levels.
Even unloading my secondary shotgun in their face at point blank doesn't seem to work very well.

Are there specific points on a dozer that are weaker? 
I have noticed after a few shots their helmet/neckarmour/facemask breaks, do we just need to shoot this until it comes off? How much damage do I need to do to break off these parts?

What guns are best for dealing with dozers?

I've heard that mines are good for this, but proximity mines sound tricky to use for killing specific enemies.

Comment: Literally, the face is your only option. Bulldozers have about 3 layers of faceplate. Once you're through the faceplate, it's just one more headshot.

Comment: Oh, Dozers. For a second I was worried.

Comment: Speaking of the faceplate: how is a bulldozer supposed to see through [that dark metal (?) thing](http://bit.ly/1a9OHdp) ?  (@DoozerBlake ! :D)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First rule of bulldozers: **try not to take one on alone.** It's hard to kill a dozer alone. Second rule of bulldozers: **aim for the face.** That's a Bulldozer's only weak point. But even that isn't very weak. You're going to want something with high damage, and a lot of focus fire to take a Bulldozer down. With enough fire at the facemask, it will eventually break, and expose a bulldozer's face for a couple final bullets.

Assault rifles are quite effective against bulldozers, since they are versatile and still effective at long range. Whatever works for you in that department, really. The AK-762 deals quite a lot of damage per bullet, and has manageable recoil. The AK-5 can be modified to have superb recoil, making the "aim for the face" part a little easier. Whatever you're comfortable with, really. (you can even use the M308, if that's your thing).

Shotguns also tend to be very good against bulldozers (though the Locomotive has a much shorter effective range), but it will still take a lot to take a bulldozer down. If shotguns are your thing, the Mosoni 12G is a superb weapon for the job, since it has such high damage output, and a decent effective range. One of its major downsides is its low ammo capacity at 26. If ammo is a concern, I would go with an assault rifle. The Reinfeld 880 is a good alternative in the shotgun department, since it still has high damage, and still a decent effective range, while carrying more rounds.

In a pinch, the Deagle and the Bronco .44 can deal significant damage to a bulldozer, however, if you have another option, I recommend using that instead. These should be saved for if you're caught without any primary ammo. The white streak, baby deagle, deagle, and peacemaker .45 can all take down a dozer in 4 hits to the face, if you're accurate.

The OVE9000 Saw is by far the *fastest* at taking down a bulldozer. However, it has some severe disadvantages, because it requires that you run at a bulldozer. So it is not the most *effective* weapon for the job by far, but if you're carrying the saw, and there's a bulldozer in your face, it takes about 2 seconds to slice right through a bulldozer's armor.

And on the point of trip mines: trip mines are effective at taking out *any* enemy within the blast radius. Ironically enough, since bulldozers wear bomb suits. I do not recommend trying to set up a trip mine really quickly in the walking path of a bulldozer. I have done it before, and it can work in a pinch if you can set it up fast and get behind something, but it is not something I would rely upon.

What I recommend (depending on the job, but the one that comes immediately to mind is Overpass Escape) is to set up several trip mines around in the general "cops will come through here" path. Odds are, you'll take out a special unit.

Comment: I just played about 3 rounds with a guy who set up a trip mine at a bulldozer's feet to take him out. I suppose it works, but it suffers from the OVE9000 problem of having to rush the guy.

Comment: Thanks to the select-fire update, I've started calling the control to toggle the 308 into burst fire mode the "Dozer Switch".

Comment: I just got the second weapon DLC today (it was on sale don't judge me), so I'm going to see how effective a LMG is as well. I have a feeling that's going to depend on your playstyle, but be generally effective.

Answer (score 4):

With the sniper dlc recentley added (month or 2 ago) the thanatos .50 cal is a dozer slayer 2 head shots (3 or 4 for a skulldozer since they have 10k hp) will definatly kill them. The .50 cal seems to have been added for this purpose though i recomend using your secondary as your main because the .50 cal only has 20 rounds and rare ammo.

Comment: I can agree with this. When ever we would do Deathwish Firestarter, we would always have 2 snipers who were tasked with killing Skulldozers. To counter the low and rare ammo, we had multiple people using the ammo bag ability (2 ammo bags, 1 med bag, 1 disrupter thing (to slow down the cloakers that spawn).

Answer (score 0):

I recommend a weapon with high damage and low recoil, such as the AMR-16, Commando 553 or P90. I prefer the last two since they have a higher ammo capacity.

Answer (score 0):

trip mines, it can blow a hole in their health, what I do is tell my crew to bait it to the trip mine while I set it up, the dozers are pretty predicatble on lower levels.

That or a sentry, get your friends to annoy the dozer then summon the sentry, at lower levels the hp is shit so you should distract the dozer away from it, summon the sentry directly behind it and although the accuracy is shit, the close range will destroy the dozer.

At higher levels with a shield and better dmg, the sentry will kill the dozer head on without dying.

A mastered sentry will destroy the dozer in a matter of seconds. (metaphorically(

Comment: Good thing I'm up for hiring

Answer (score 0):

With the new Overkill DLC rocket launcher, if you hit a dozer from any side of his head it is an instant kill.

Comment: Point of order, DLC isn't really an update

Answer (score 0):

As previously mentioned, you have the classic "Sit back with the ARs and pop them in the head" strategy that everyone is so fond of. Weapons with lots of bullets in a magazine and a good rate of fire can shred a dozer up close, but lower recoil ones such as the UAR are better for hanging back and putting rounds on him at range. SMGs, as well, can accomplish this. Just make sure you're aiming for the head.

The 3 variations of the Dozer are pretty basic, with basic Dozers carrying a Reinfeld, the black Killdozers carrying the Izhma 12, and the Skulldozers wielding a KSP LMG. The former two are equally easy to deal with, although the Killdozer stands more of a chance to punch back if you're shotgunning them down with his Autoshotty. The Skulldozer's KSP will shred you like butter, so stay back and hit them with a weapon the like a sniper rifle (The Thanatos will drop a skulldozer in 3 hits to the body) or the M14 (If you lack the sniper DLC)

The controversial set is shotguns. Without any DLC, your best bet is either A: The Izhma (Saiga 12), as the reload is short, and if you fail to kill the dozer in a magazine, you can drop around a corner, reload, and repeat. B: The Mosconi, with its high accuracy, high damage, and decent ammo pickup, it's a strong weapon on Overkill and below for sure, although shotgun skills aid it far more than any other option in the base game. With each barrel, if you're accurate, will drop the faceplate and visor in one shot apiece. This leaves an exposed face for your teammates to deposit lead into. For soloing a Dozer (Which, if you have the gear and the know-how is easy, regardless of what others have said) reload and put the remaining two into his face and he will go down. Finally, is the Locomotive 12. When properly modded, you can get 10 shells to a magazine, which is enough to drop Killdozers and standard Bulldozers. (But not Skulldozers) When one is in killing range, take your 10 rounds and blast off his vizor and faceplate (Usually 2 rounds each) and unload your remaining 6 into his squishy face. This is the most risky, as you have a good chance of being shot back by the dozer, so a good armor set is advised.

I've read a lot of praise for the Reinfeld, but from personal experience the other primaries are a better choice, and the Loco can be carried in a secondary slot.

As of the BBQ pack, the AA-12 serves the exact same purpose as the Saiga, but with the ability to hold 20 rounds in the drum mag (an attachment given upon purchase) and does not require the Tech's Mag Plus skill to get an insane amount of ammo between reloads.

Answer (score 0):

If you're playing the meltdown level, you can actually run them over while driving a forklift. It's an instant kill. I've only tried this on one of the easier settings, but I'm pretty sure they die from getting run over, just like any other unit.

Answer (score -1):

I read much bullocks here. dozers have 5.5K HP with a 22,xx headshot multiplier, that means theoratically you need to put arround ~240 dam in his face.

But he has semi bulletproof armor, you have his face plate and the glass plate of 180Hp and 150Hp. before these 2 are destroyed every shot counts as a body shot regardless where you hit him, in other word. when the face and glass plates are still intact it matters shit where you hit em, after these are destroyed he needs a final push of arround ~240 in his face to die.

To kill one, use HIGH EXPLOSIVE ordanance, either a GL40 or any shotgun with HE ammo, idk how but this works slighly different when it commes to breaking his vizor. as you know HE shotgun shells cant kill nothing but shields and dozervizors and nothing else! the advantage of HE weaponry is that it also stuns the dozer, very usefull if mr black one aims an automatic shotgun at you.

thanatos can 2 shot kill one, you dont have to make headshots with it. but thanatos sux as every non special kill is a waste of ammo.

further you can use every automatic weapon with one fist rule, it has to have high DPS. amr16
stryck18c, desert eagle, etc

Do not use shotguns with any-other-not-HE-ammo-type. shotguns might deal 100 damage, but the rof is so slow your dps is shit. especially do not use the mosconi, it is beyond useless to kill a bulldozer with that

Answer (score -1):

Akimbo with fast rate of fire + Low Blow. It's a basically 60% headshot chancez

Comment: how this explain the OP question?